# Given an html string, convert all img src attributes from relative to absolute (Node / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a raw string of html on a node server.

I need to convert all of the img src attributes from relative to absolute.

What is the best (simplest) way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably using string manipulation methods, maybe a find/replace, etc

Comment: Parse the html into https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom and use jQuery to update the attributes.

Comment: convert before sending to server using `attr(function(idx,attr){})`

Comment: Where do you send the raw string of html from? If it's from a browser, then consider doing the manipulation client-side, which will be simpler and faster.

Comment: It has to be done server side, unfortunately -- as the html is generated using a Jade template.